# installing debian package programmatically using libapt-pkg

Tags: c++, debian, apt, package-managers

I need to install some packages in my c++ program, so I've written the following code :

```
    pkgInitConfig(*_config);
    pkgInitSystem(*_config, _system);

    pkgCacheFile cache_file;
    pkgCache *cache = cache_file.GetPkgCache();
    pkgDepCache *dep_cache = cache_file.GetDepCache();
    pkgPackageManager *pm = new pkgPackageManager(dep_cache);

    for(pkgCache::PkgIterator package = cache->PkgBegin(); !package.end(); package++)
    {
        if((*package).CurrentState == pkgCache::State::NotInstalled)
        {
            if(package.Name() == "MyPkgName")
                if(dep_cache->MarkInstall(package))
                {
                    std::cout << "Marked" << std::endl;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    APT::Progress::PackageManager *progress =   APT::Progress::PackageManagerProgressFactory();
    pkgPackageManager::OrderResult rs = pm->DoInstall(progress);

    if(rs == pkgPackageManager::Completed)
        std::cout << "Completed" << std::endl;
    else if (rs == pkgPackageManager::Failed)
        std::cout << "Failed!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "InComplete!" << std::endl;
```

It seems that this block of code is doing it's job and the result of `pm->DoInstall()` function is `pkgPackageManager::Completed`, but when I try to install this package from command line apt-get doesn't say that the package is installed! Actually package is not installed.

So is there anything wrong with this code? anything more needed to do for installation to be complete?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your error, but I got many linking errors before executing. Are you using cmake? If yes, could you show the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?